# Angular 2 - How to insert variable in component

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to dynamically load a component. So I tried this approach but it didn't worked:

```
<page-{{current_page}}></page-{{current_page}}>
```

Currently I'm using this approach but it doesn't seems efficient:

```
<div *ngIf="current_page==1">
    <page-1></page-1>
</div>
<div *ngIf="current_page==2">
    <page-2></page-2>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Why you need dynamic directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported. String interpolation `{{}}` can only be used for property-**values** and element-content, but not for element-names or attribute-names.

Perhaps `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` can do what you need.

For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

If you have a limited set of components you want to display, `*ngIf` or `ngSwitchCase` is the way to go.